# Why is it that when viewing the architecture in Netron, the normalization layer that goes right after the convolutional layer is not shown?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I test some changes on a Convolutional neural network architecture. I tried to add BatchNorm layer right after conv layer and than add activation layer. Then I swapped activation layer with BatchNorm layer.

```
# here example of conv-> b_norm -> activation
...
nn.Conv2d(out_, out_, kernel_size=(1, 3), padding=(0, 1), bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(out_),
nn.LeakyReLU(),
...

# here example of conv-> activation -> b_norm 
...
nn.Conv2d(out_, out_, kernel_size=(1, 3), padding=(0, 1), bias=False),
nn.LeakyReLU(),
nn.BatchNorm2d(out_),
...
```

I have noticed that in Netron (app for visualization NN architectures) there is NO batch_norm in architecture with b_norm right after conv, but there is in the other one with b_norm after activation.
So my question is: Does the normalization layer after convolution have any special meaning or is there something wrong with the netron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you cannot see Batch Norm when it follows convolution operation has to do with **Batch Norm Folding**. The convolution operation followed by Batch Norm can be replaced with just one convolution only with different weights.

I assume, for Netron visualization you first convert to ONNX format.

In PyTorch, Batch Norm Folding optimization is performed by default by `torch.onnx.export`, where eval mode is default one. You can disable this behavior by converting to ONNX in train mode:

`torch.onnx.export(..., training=TrainingMode.TRAINING,...)`

Then you should be able to see all Batch Norm layers in your graph.