# How to record the Batch Normalization layers under the ONNX format?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, onnx

I need to print the structure of a neural network from a Pytorch code. I resorted to use ONNX format: I used the `torch.onnx.export` function, but what happens is that the Batch Normalization layers are not recorded, since they are included in the convolutional layers (see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/40547) and [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/49226), for example). After some search, I found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69131168/13156261) on StackOverflow, which seems to provide a solution to the above problem, by adding the option `training=TrainingMode.TRAINING`. Unfortunately, as noted also by others on the web, this option seems to not work, as such option does not seem to be recognized.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-208-8820886c111a> in <module>
     10                   input_names = ['input'],
     11                   output_names = ['output'],
---> 12                   training=TrainingMode.TRAINING)
     13 
     14 

NameError: name 'TrainingMode' is not defined
```

Below I provide an example code for showing the problem, I am currently working on Colab.

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch import nn

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(f"Using {device} device")

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
    self.Network = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(1,1,3),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(1,track_running_stats=False),
        nn.ReLU(),
    )

  def forward(self,x):
    output = self.Network(x)
    return output

model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)

print(model)

import onnx

net=NeuralNetwork()
torch.onnx.export(net, dummy_input, "test.onnx", 
                  verbose=True, 
                  export_params=True, 
                  opset_version=12,
                  do_constant_folding=True,
                  input_names = ['input'], 
                  output_names = ['output'],
                  training=TrainingMode.TRAINING)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import definition of `TrainingMode`

with import:

```
from torch.onnx import TrainingMode
```

without import:

```
torch.onnx.TrainingMode.TRAINING
```

After that you can successfully export onnx model (visualized with [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)):

[image]

Comment: Great! Do you have a reference where this import is documented? Another question (I do not know it is worth to ask on the stack): is it possible to get rid off all those steps (reshape-Transpose-ReduceMean-etc ect) and have just the Batch normalization layer?

Comment: You can check it in the official docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/onnx.html#export .  ReduceMean/Sub/Mul steps are part of the model when BatchNorm does not contain the running stats and estimates it during evaluation. You can set `track_running_stats=True` (default behavior) to get rid of them.